# Custom shadow with CSS

Tags: css, box-shadow

How do I make a shadow per the image below? I don't have any idea how to do that.

[image: A curved shadow]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any CSS code?

Comment: nope, now i'm working on that.

Comment: So when you have some code to show us please update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is by styling the pesedo elements `::before` and `::after` like this:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 15px 0px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}

div::after {
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This see [pen](https://codepen.io/haibnu/pen/FxGsI) for more shadow styling.

Comment: thanks, now its more look alike. Also how bout curved block?

Comment: One way to do a curve block (or give the illusion of one) is to create a large radial background-gradient and position it accordingly. Also, if you place the shadow element over another element it might give that effect.

Comment: Could you help me with this curve?

Comment: I think this merits to open a new question. I also recommend reading more about radial gradients here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient